# Google Map API v3 - show all visible markers with maximum zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a page where I can toggle on/off categories of markers. One marker (the 'property') will always be visible. I would like to zoom in as close as possible showing all visible markers.

So, if I have 3 markers close together I would like to zoom in all close as possible while still fitting the 3 markers.

```
var fullBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var map;
var infowindow;
var markers = {};
var nearbyPlaces = {{#property}}{{{stringify nearbyPlaces}}}{{/property}};
var property = new google.maps.LatLng({{#property}}{{address.geo.lat}},{{address.geo.lng}}{{/property}});
var name = {{#property}}{{{stringify name}}}{{/property}}
var prop = {{#property}}{{{stringify address}}}{{/property}};


function initialize() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: property,
        zoom: 15
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: '../../../../img/map/property.png', // Set Property to a green marker
        position: property
    });

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // Set infowindow for the property
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.setContent(name + '<br/>' + prop.street + '<br/>' + prop.city + ', ' + prop.state.name);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });

    var l = nearbyPlaces.length;
    while (l--) {
        markers[nearbyPlaces[l].category] = [];
        createCategory(nearbyPlaces[l]);
    }

    console.log(map.getZoom());
}

function createCategory(item) {
    var l = item.places.length;
    while (l--) {
        var marker = createMarker(item.places[l]);
        markers[item.category].push(marker);
        console.log(item.category);

        switch(item.category){
            case 'Public Schools':
                marker.icon = '../../../../img/map/public_school.png';
                break;
            case 'Colleges':
                marker.icon = '../../../../img/map/college.png';
                break;
            case 'Preferred Employers':
                marker.icon = '../../../../img/map/work.png';
                break;
            default:
                marker.icon = '../../../../img/map/star.png'
        }

    }
}

function toggleCategory(name, el) {
    //map.fitBounds(fullBounds);
    var button = $(el);
    var visible = true;

    if (button.hasClass('active')) {
        visible = false;
    }

    button.toggleClass('active');


    var category = markers[name];
    for (var x = 0; x < category.length; x++){
        var lat = category[x].position.k;
        var lng = category[x].position.B;
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        fullBounds.extend(point);
    }

    var l = category.length;
    console.log('cagegory length: ' + category.length);
    while (l--) {
        category[l].setVisible(visible);
    }

    showVisible();

}

function createMarker(place) {
//var lat = parseFloat(place.address.geo.lat);
//var lng = parseFloat(place.address.geo.lng);
//var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
//fullBounds.extend(point);
//console.log(place);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: place.title,
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png',  // Set all other markers to red...
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(place.address.geo.lat, place.address.geo.lng)
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.setContent(place.title + '<br/>' + place.address.street + '<br/>' + place.address.city + ', ' + place.address.state.name);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });

    return marker;
}


function showVisible() {



    // FIT ONLY VISIBLE MARKERS

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I do is after creating the Map instance and before creating any Marker instances is create a [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#LatLngBounds) instance. Then as I create my markers, I call the extend method of the LatLngBounds instance for each Marker created:

```
myLatLngBounds.extend( myMarker.getPosition() );
```

After all the markers are made, I call fitBounds on my map instance passing it the LatLngBounds:

```
myMap.fitBounds( myLatLngBounds );
```

Comment: Doesn't this fitBounds on all markers created? How could I apply this to only fitBounds of visible markers?

Comment: @Mithrilhall It will fitBounds for all the markers that you passed to 'extend' on the LatLngBounds. If you don't want to bound to be effected by certain markers, do not extend the LatLngBounds for the markers LatLng.

Answer (score 2):

these two lines did the trick for me:

```
bounds.extend(marker.position); 
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

you're going to have to adapt this to your script though as this was taken directly from one of mine.

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Declare a new Google maps LatLngBounds object

```
var mapLatLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

... then for each marker, extend the map bounds

```
mapLatLngBounds.extend(marker.position);
```

For your map, set the center and bounds, based on the bounds that we've now defined

```
myMap.setCenter(mapLatLngBounds.getCenter());
myMap.fitBounds(mapLatLngBounds);
```

> Marker positions are LatLng objects which is why you can pass them straight to the *extend* function. If you're dealing with custom location objects that specify *lat* and *lng* somehow, then when you're looping/creating locations, you'll need to create LatLng objects that you can pass to the *extend* function:
>
> ```
> var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLocations[i].Latitude, myLocations[i].Longitude);
> mapLatLngBounds.extend(latlng);
> ```